# Page Performance : by using data-attribute vs Class

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I have a question, regarding the performance of web page using data-attr or class.

For example I have 1000 elements in my dom structure, if I add data-attr to each dom element or if i add unique class to each dom element, which one will impact page performance badly?

Also what is the better attribute should use in this scenario data-attr or class.

```
<div data-attr="test">Using data attr</div>

<div class="test">Using class</div>
```

Comment: These are not replacements for each other. To perform `query selection`, go for `class` and to maintain element related information, use `data-*` attributes!

Comment: I think the real answer to this question is use what's most appropriate for your use case. The performance difference is probably trivial, but you haven't specified the purpose of applying the class/attribute.